# Socket.IO: Invoke custom function instead of using socket.on

Tags: socket.io

Is there a way I can define a custom `function (name,data,callback)` which is then invoked by socket.io when a client sends a function call?

Instead of using `socket.on(name,function(data,callback){...})` socket.io should call my function. This would make it much easier to implement logic that is needed in every socket.io function and I wouldn't need to call `socket.on` for a whole stack of rpc functions on each connection.

I checked socket.io wiki but didn't find anything related.

I know I could implement a "rpc server" on top of socket.io like this, but it would be better to use socket.io's native way.

```
socket.on('rpc',function(data,callback){ /* e.g. data.name for function name, data.data for the actual data */});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I get it. Can't you do something like this?

Server:

```
function handleMessage(name, data, callback) {
  // ...
}

// listen on all kind of messages
socket.on('message', handleMessage);
```

Client:

```
socket.send(name, data, callback);
```

This way you just use Socket.IO as a WebSockets wrapper.

If you are looking for something more fancy maybe you should check out [nowjs](http://nowjs.org/) or [dnode](https://github.com/substack/dnode).

Comment: `socket.send` does only support 2 parameters: data and callback. However callback is bugged (filed bug report here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/645 ). I'm actually doing it like you suggested right now (with bugfix). I send with `socket.json.send([name,data],cb)`. (json message flag)

Comment: Hm, maybe `send` is not supposed to have a callback, I'm not sure. You could always revert to `emit` for the time being since you will just have one binding anyway and it will be easy to change it in future. Any other reason for not using `emit` other than aesthetics?

Comment: ??? How is it supposed that the handleMessage() function *at the server side* will be able to call `callback` *at the client side*?????